# SSRS Generate multiple different reports and save dialog all of them simultaneously

Tags: c#, reporting-services, pdf-generation

I have have a report that I am opening on a button click which allows the user to save the report. I will require multiple reports to run simultaneously was wondering if instead of saving them individually, or opening them one at a time, is there was a way to batch reports and use one save dialog to save them all to the same folder location? Each report has its own dataset and will be run one after the other and all need to be saved to the same folder by the user.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to create a "master" report and add all your reports as subreports.

The master report should have all the parameters required to run the subreports.

You can put a page break at the end of each subreport in order to be separated in the exported file (eg. for excel each report will be in each own sheet).

You can also use bookmarks for each subreport in order to create a report index (in excel it creates a sheet with links to individual reports).

Comment: Would this work for pdf's? As in would you be able to do a single save dialog and save 20 or so reports to a folder?

Comment: It creates a single pdf file with bookmarks for each report